# preg_replace not working or am I doing it wrong?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have this as part of a `preg_replace` array

```
// CENTER ITEMS
$pattern[5] = '/\[center\](.*?)\[\/center\]/i';
$replace[5] = "<div class=\"centerText\">$1</div>";
```

It works as long as whatever it is finding is like

`[center]lol[/center]`

But if the text is like

`[center]hello`

`my name is steve`
`[/center]`

It does not work how can I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the "s" modifier, which will include newlines in the match text.

> **s (PCRE_DOTALL)** If this modifier is set, a dot metacharacter in the pattern matches all characters, including newlines. Without it,
>   newlines are excluded. This modifier is equivalent to Perl's /s
>   modifier. A negative class such as [^a] always matches a newline
>   character, independent of the setting of this modifier.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php